# How to access enum by index key in rust

Tags: rust

I have a function which returns a type of `Option<Month>`

```
pub fn month_from_index(index: u64) -> Option<Month>
```

It essentially returns a integer from 1-12

The underlying type definition

**Datetimeutils**

```
/// Converts an integer in the range 1-12 into the corresponding `Month` enum.
/// Values outside the 1-12 range are converted to `None`.
pub fn month_from_index(index: u64) -> Option<Month> {
    match index {
        1 => Some(Month::January),
        2 => Some(Month::February),
        3 => Some(Month::March),
        4 => Some(Month::April),
        5 => Some(Month::May),
        6 => Some(Month::June),
        7 => Some(Month::July),
        8 => Some(Month::August),
        9 => Some(Month::September),
        10 => Some(Month::October),
        11 => Some(Month::November),
        12 => Some(Month::December),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

I can get the current month which takes in a u64, which will work with the function `month_from_index`.

```
let month = Utc::now().month() as u64;
```

Now... i want to get the days of the month dynamically. This `days_in_month` function only takes an enum, which makes it tricky.

**main.rs**

```
use chrono::prelude::*;
use datetimeutils::{day_string, days_in_month, month_from_index, month_string, Month};
use slint::VecModel;
use std::rc::Rc;
slint::include_modules!();

fn generate_month(year: u64, month: Option<Month>) -> u64 {
    days_in_month(year, month) /// if i replace month with Month::January it works. But i want this to be be accessed via index. 
}

fn load_calendar(boxes: Rc<VecModel<NewBox>>, year: u64) {
    let current_date = chrono::Utc::now();
    let month = Utc::now().month() as u64;
    let current_month = month_from_index(month);
    let generate_days = generate_month(year, current_month);
    for new_box in 0..generate_days {
        boxes.insert(
            new_box as usize,
            NewBox {
                visible: true,
                day: new_box as i32 + 1,
            },
        )
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), slint::PlatformError> {
    let ui = AppWindow::new()?;
    let boxes = Rc::new(slint::VecModel::<NewBox>::from(Vec::new()));

    let new_boxes = boxes.clone();

    load_calendar(new_boxes, 2024);

    ui.set_boxes(boxes.into());

    ui.run()
}
```

[image]

```
 --> src/main.rs:8:25
  |
8 |     days_in_month(year, month)
  |     -------------       ^^^^^ expected `Month`, found `Option<Month>`
  |
  |
  |     arguments to this function are incorrect
  |   = note: expected enum `datetimeutils::Month`              found enum `std::option::Option<datetimeutils::Month>`
```

Comment: [The book explains `Option` and how to work with it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html?highlight=option#the-option-enum-and-its-advantages-over-null-values)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue by using `unwrap`

```
fn generate_month(year: u64, month: Option<Month>) -> u64 {
    days_in_month(year, month.unwrap())
}
```

However im not so sure why this works.